# Error: [GoogleMaps]You need to execute "$> ionic cordova run browser"."$> ionic serve" is not supported

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic4

I am using ionic 4 beta, exactly ionic 4.3.1 and I added google map native like this [tutorial](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.g282d0a7bfd_0_158)

But when I run this command `ionic cordova run android` I get this error on map page:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: [GoogleMaps]You need to execute "$> ionic cordova run browser"."$> ionic serve" is not supported.

I am using:

Node 10.13.0

Windows 10

Cordova 7.1.0

Ionic 4.3.1

Please, someone can help me please

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device?

Comment: facing same issue, incase of livereload this error is shown else google map working fine

Answer (score -3):

just run

```
Ionic cordova run browser
```

Comment: That doesn't help when you're trying to test it on a real device, which is the problem OP described.